# Denied access to a specific file but allow access to that file after login

Tags: php, pdf, hyperlink, access-denied

i want to do denied access to a file!
I send a pdf link to a friend like this: http://www.domain.com/pdf/name.pdf
When my friend try to access that pdf link i want to denied access and redirect to a login page and here after i insert user name and password to access that pdf!

Thank you for anything!

Update: After i search and read some stuff i made like this and is work's beautiful, above is the code:

```html
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomainname/pdf/ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomainname/pdf/.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^pdf(/.*)\.(gif|jpg|pdf)$ - [F]
ErrorDocument 403  /error/index.php
```

Comment: I suggest you start reading a few basic documentations. This is standard, well documented and easy to find on the internet.

Comment: Setup a CMS, which offers private access to resources. You can then add an account for your friend.

Answer (score 1):

you should use simple .htaccess authentication

/path/to/pdf/.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "protected area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/pdf/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

/path/to/pdf/.htpasswd

the password must be crypted and base64  encoded.

```
myusername:$apr1$EzX1xHNv$NgbgAnflbfzjI0Vhxwv8q.
```

you can run the following PHP script in order to get a correct password value for your htpasswd file

```
<?php
// Password to be encrypted for a .htpasswd file
$clearTextPassword = 'some password';

// Encrypt password
$password = crypt($clearTextPassword, base64_encode($clearTextPassword));

// Print encrypted password
echo $password;
?>
```

when someone will try to connect to this url, they will be prompted for authentication

[image]

Comment: You can also use the program [htpasswd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some logic in the server side before donwload the PDF file, first you need a server page that check if the user is logged in (check for session in php manual), only if the user has session you execute the login to download the pdf file (check for Donwloading pdf files from php), if the user is not loggedin in you redirect the user to a login page, and finally in the login page server side, when you check the user is valid you set the data of the user in session from database for example.

A very simple example will be like this:

```
//donwloadpdf.php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {

    session_start();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { //user not logged in

    redirect('login_page.php');

}

//user logged in
header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile("PD_FILE.pdf");
```

You need to read about session and download files, and also you need to put the login in objects with its own responsability.

And some very simple example of your login_page.php in the server side will be like this:

```
//login_page.php
//if is POST
//put some real logic to check if the user is valid
if (true) {

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1; //put real data from database

}
//end of logic to check if the user is valid
```